# Applications running even before logging in

Tags: security, windows-10

1. I have google chrome playing a show on Netflix. (Windows Version 1709 build 16299.192)
2. with the show playing I shutdown the computer (really shutdown)
3. I turn on the computer and am now on the logon screen to type my password to logon
4. I hear sound coming out of my headphones
5. W T F!!! I haven't login yet but I can hear the show I was watching before I shut down the computer.....

What am  I doing wrong??? some configuration missing maybe?

Comment: I was able to opt out of this feature in version 1709 build 16299 by disabling the option to "use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up..." under settings -> accounts -> sign-in options. You can also use the classic shutdown dialog via Alt+F4 on the desktop, or use the command `shutdown.exe /s /f /t 0`.

Comment: FYI, applications have been able to register to run on restart since Vista, via [`RegisterApplicationRestart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373347). This requires exiting Windows with the flag [`EWX_RESTARTAPPS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868), e.g. via `shutdown.exe /sg /t 0`. The change in Windows 10 is to allow logging on in the background while still requiring the user to log on normally to show the default desktop. They should really tweak this to disconnect or mute the session's audio. It's definitely a privacy bug.

Comment: Thank you. Holy cow, this is a real privacy issue. Oh  well, another reason not to watch porn on the PC :D